# Import ActiveDirectory Powershell module on macOS

Tags: macos, powershell, active-directory

is it possible to import the ActiveDirectory Powershell module on macOS? Apparantly it is not available on Powershell Gallery, but only part of the RSAT.

Maybe it is possible to copy the module from Windows (`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\ActiveDirectory`)? But I guess it has dependencies, that are only available on Windows?

This command fails:

```
Import-Module ./ActiveDirectory.psd1
Import-Module: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```